# How to correctly use I-Splines for monotone non-decreasing/ increasing regression?

Tags: regression, splines, intercept, basis-function

I have the following data to which I want to fit a monotone non-decreasing spline.

```r
x <- c(300, 377, 455, 533, 611, 688, 766, 844, 922, 1000)  
y <- c(0.5, 0.8, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)
```

To achieve this, I use an I-Spline basis (i.e., `splines2::iSpline`) paired with non-negative coefficients (i.e., `nnls::nnls`).

```r
# Inner knots.
k <- quantile(x, probs = c(.25, .5, .75))

h <- splines2::iSpline(x, knots = k, Boundary.knots = range(x), intercept = TRUE)
a <- nnls::nnls(h, y)$x
```

And this gives me the following:

```r
# Fitted.
f <- h %*% a

print(f)
#             [,1]
#   [1,] 0.0000000
#   [2,] 0.8106201
#   [3,] 0.9699174
#   [4,] 0.9992354
#   [5,] 1.0035000
#   [6,] 1.0035515
#   [7,] 1.0035515
#   [8,] 1.0035515
#   [9,] 1.0035515
#  [10,] 1.0035515
```

However, with `intercept = TRUE`, I would expect the spline to start somewhere above the first data point. For instance, this seems to be the case when I set the first basis function to 1.

```r
h[, 1] <- 1
```

If I set `intercept = FALSE`, then things go haywire.

[image]

**Can you please help me understand what is going on**, i.e., why is the spline not starting at `(300, 0.5)`?

---

#### Further Details

I want to clarify my question further. My confusion stems from what is written in [this paper](http://deleeuwpdx.net/pubfolders/splines/splines.pdf) on p. 15:

> To get a basis for the increasing splines we need to add the constant function to the I-splines and allow it to enter the linear combination with either sign.

In the `splines2` package documentation, where the intercept argument for `iSpline()` is described, it says:

> Notice that when using I-Spline for monotonic regression, `intercept = TRUE` should be set even when an intercept term is considered additional to the spline bases in the model.

What I get from this is that if I want to fit a monotone spline with, say, `nnls::nnls()`, then I need to add a constant function to the I-Spline basis, i.e., `h <- cbind(1, h)`, assuming that `h` is the basis matrix output of `iSpline()`.

However, in the paper linked above, that's not always the case. Sometimes the author replaces the first column of the basis matrix (i.e., `h <- cbind(1, h[ -1]`) with the constant function, and, other times, he appends the constant function to the basis matrix.

For instance, if I create the I-Spline basis matrix as follows:

```r
h <- splines2::iSpline(x, knots = c(3, 5, 8), degree = 0, intercept = TRUE)
```

Then, depending on how I "add" the constant function (or not) I get different splines:

[image: splines_question]

What's not clear to me is how the basis matrix provided by `iSpline()` is intended to be used in this case.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looking back at this question after asking the author of the `splines2` package for more details, I feel like I owe a clarification, which may also qualify as an answer. The following is based heavily on two GitHub issues that I opened [here](https://github.com/wenjie2wang/splines2/issues/4) (#4) and [here](https://github.com/wenjie2wang/splines2/issues/6) (#6). I am posting it here in case it might help someone in the future.

In issue #4 I was confused because I didn't understand how exactly to use *I-Splines* in the context of regression. My goal was to use *I-Splines* to fit monotone non-increasing or non-decreasing splines.

I found your package `splines2` and the code of [De Leeuw (2017)](https://github.com/wenjie2wang/splines2/files/6348513/de_leeuw_2017_splines.pdf) online and that helped to contrast and compare the approaches. I learned that `splines2` creates *I-Splines* based on [Ramsay (1988)](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/statistical-science/volume-3/issue-4/Monotone-Regression-Splines-in-Action/10.1214/ss/1177012761.full) who uses *M-Splines* as a starting point. On the other side, De Leeuw (2017) constructs *I-Splines* using *N-Splines* as a starting point. Both approaches are not approximate, but equivalent. So, I was confused when using the same configuration of knots I got different `I-Splines`.

It turns out that both Ramsay (1988) and De Leeuw (2017) use in fact *B-Splines*, but normalized differently. Ramsay (1988) uses *B-Splines* that are normalized such that they integrate to one (i.e., these are called *M-Splines*). Whereas for De Leeuw (2017), the *B-Splines* are normalized such that they sum to one (i.e., which he calls normalized *B-Splines*, or *N-Splines*). Also, it appears that Ramsay (1988) refers to *N-Splines* simply as *B-Splines* in his paper. This seems to also be the case with `splines2::bSpline()` which actually returns normalized B-Splines that sum to one, i.e., *N-Splines*.

Indeed, normalized *B-Splines* and *M-Splines* *look* the same, and we can see that they only differ with respect to the normalization (i.e., `y` axis).

```r
# The data.
x = 1:10

# The inner knots.
innerknots = c(5)

# The degree.
degree = 2

# Creating normalized `B-Splines` and `M-Splines`.
b <- splines2::bSpline(x, knots = innerknots, degree = degree, intercept = TRUE)
m <- splines2::mSpline(x, knots = innerknots, degree = degree, intercept = TRUE)

# Plotting the spline bases.
matplot(b, type = "l", lwd = 2, main = paste0("Normalized B-Splines | degree = ", degree))
matplot(m, type = "l", lwd = 2, main = paste0("M-Splines | degree = ", degree))
```

[image]

Now, onto creating *I-Splines*, Ramsay (1988) says that they can be created by taking the integrals of *M-Splines*. Which is what the argument `integral` in `splines2::mSpline()` does, or what the function `splines2::iSpline()` provides.

```r
# Taking integrals of `M-Splines` and creating `I-Splines`.
mi <- splines2::mSpline(x, knots = innerknots, degree = degree, intercept = TRUE, integral = TRUE)
i <- splines2::iSpline(x, knots = innerknots, degree = degree, intercept = TRUE)

# Plotting the spline basis.
matplot(mi, type = "l", lwd = 2, main = paste0("Integrals of M-Splines | degree = ", degree))
matplot(i, type = "l", lwd = 2, main = paste0("I-Splines | degree = ", degree))
```

[image]

De Leeuw (1988; p. 17) refers to a formula (see below) from [De Boor (1976)](https://ftp.cs.wisc.edu/Approx/survey76.pdf) and says:

> This shows that I-splines can be computed by using cumulative sums of B-spline values.

To be more precise, I believe this should read as "*sums of normalized B-spline values*".

$$
\int_{-\infty}^{x} M_{j, m}(t) d t=\sum_{\ell=j}^{j+r} N_{\ell, m+1}(x)
$$

There are two things to note. First, De Leeuw (2017) uses `m` to refer to the order of a spline while Ramsay (1988) refers to the degree. If I am not mistaken the relationship should be `degree = order - 1`. Second, and most importantly, the equation above shows that integrals of *M-Splines* of order `m` are equivalent to cumulative sums of normalized *B-Splines* of order `m + 1`.

Indeed, it seems that by the equation above we can obtain the same *I-Splines*. So, above I used the `splines2::iSpline()` to create *I-Splines* of `degree = 2`. Thus, if I want to use cumulative sums to get the same *I-Splines*, I need normalized *B-splines* that are one degree higher, i.e., `degree = 2 + 1`.

```r
# Create normalized `B-Splines` of one degree higher.
b2 <- splines2::bSpline(x, knots = innerknots, degree = degree + 1, intercept = TRUE)

# Now take the cumulative sums as De Leeuw (2017) shows in the paper. 
# And remove the redundant column of zeros at the end of the basis matrix. 
ci <- 1 - t(apply(b2, 1, cumsum))
ci <- ci[, -ncol(ci)]

# And, indeed, these are the same splines as those provided by `splines2::iSpline()`.
all(round(i, 10) == round(ci, 10))

# Plot the spline bases.
matplot(i, type = "l", lwd = 2, main = paste0("I-Splines | degree = ", degree))
matplot(ci, type = "l", lwd = 2, main = paste0("Cumulative sums of normalized B-Splines | degree = ", degree))
```

[image]

I was happy when I saw this equivalence. My *first confusion* came from the fact that I overlooked the `m + 1` part in the equation, and this sent me down the rabbit hole of chasing intercepts...

Related to my *second confusion*, Ramsay (1988; p. 428) says:

> We shall use the term order k to refer to an M-spline of degree k - 1 or the associated I-spline of degree k.

I tried to replicate this with `splines2`, but I couldn't observe the same. For example, I expected to be able to obtain the *I-Splines* above (i.e., stored in `i`), constructed with  `degree = 2`, by taking integrals of M-Splines constructed with `degree = 2 - 1`. But that doesn't seem to be the case.

```r
# Create `M-Splines` of one degree lower.
mspline <- splines2::mSpline(x, knots = innerknots, degree = degree - 1, intercept = TRUE, integral = TRUE)

# Plotting the `M-Splines`.
matplot(mspline, type = "l", lwd = 2, main = paste0("Integrals of M-Splines | degree = ", degree))

# But the `I-Splines` with `degree = 2` look like:
matplot(i, type = "l", lwd = 2, main = paste0("I-Splines | degree = ", degree))
```

[image]

The author of `splines2` clarifies this in #6 and he points me to the documentation that reads:

> The degree of I-spline defined to be the degree of the associated M-spline instead of actual polynomial degree. For example, I-spline basis of degree 2 is defined as the integral of associated M-spline basis of degree 2.

Based on this piece of information and the equation above that links integrals of *M-Splines* with cumulative sums of *N-Splines*, it becomes clear that if I want an *I-Spline* basis of `degree = 3`, then I can obtain this from integrals of *M-Splines* of `degree = 2`, which will be identical to cumulative sums of *N-Splines* of `degree = 3`. And, indeed this seems to be the case:

```r
# Creating normalized `B-Splines` of degree 3.
nspline <- splines2::bSpline(x, knots = innerknots, degree = 3, intercept = TRUE)

# Computing I-Splines as cumulative sums of normalized `B-Splines`.
cumsum_nspline <- 1 - t(apply(nspline, 1, cumsum))
cumsum_nspline <- cumsum_nspline[, -ncol(cumsum_nspline)]

# Computing integrals of `M-Splines` of degree 2.
integrals_mspline <- splines2::mSpline(x, knots = innerknots, degree = 2, intercept = TRUE, integral = TRUE)

# Computing `I-Splines` of degree 2 associated with the `M-Splines`.
ispline <- splines2::iSpline(x, knots = innerknots, degree = 2, intercept = TRUE)

# Plotting the spline bases.
matplot(cumsum_nspline, type = "l", lwd = 2, main = paste0("Cumulative Sums Normalized B-Splines | degree = ", 2))
matplot(integrals_mspline, type = "l", lwd = 2, main = paste0("Integrals M-Splines | degree = ", 2))
matplot(ispline, type = "l", lwd = 2, main = paste0("I-Splines w/ M-Spline associated degree | degree = ", 2))
```

[image]

To come full circle, my *third confusion* was related to how the *I-Spline* basis should properly be used for monotone regression. I noticed that, despite the fact that De Leeuw (2017) provides the *I-Spline* basis with the constant function already appended as the first basis function, at one point he drops the first basis function and appends another column of ones (i.e., `g <- cbind (1, h[,-1])`). This looks odd, but it seems to be a choice given the data he was modeling.

Neverthless, in the paper De Leeuw (2017, p.15) states:

> Non-negative linear combinations I-splines can be used as a basis for the convex cone of increasing splines. Note, however, that if we use an extended partition, then all I-splines start at value zero and end at value one, which means their convex combinations are the splines that are also probability distributions on the interval. To get a basis for the increasing splines we need to add the constant function to the I-splines and allow it to enter the linear combination with either sign.

Thus, it seems that to properly uses *I-Spline* bases for fitting monotone non-decreasing or non-increasing splines, one needs to:

1. add a constant function to the *I-Spline* basis
2. leave the first parameter unconstrained (i.e., the parameter associated with the constant function; the intercept)
3. constrain all other parameters to be non-negative (i.e., for a monotone non-decreasing spline) or non-positive (i.e., for a monotone non-increasing spline)

There are different approaches to estimate given such constraints, but, as [Tom Wenseleers](https://stats.stackexchange.com/users/27340/tom-wenseleers) points in his [answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/415171/116619) (i.e., also see the edits for his answer), one can express the problem as a quadratic programming problem and use `quadprog` or `osqp`. For instance, using `quadprog::solve.QP()` this might look like:

```r
# Create `I-Spline` basis.
ispline <- splines2::iSpline(x, knots = innerknots, degree = 2, intercept = TRUE)

# Add constant to `I-Spline` basis.
ispline <- cbind(1, ispline)

# Fit monotone non-decreasing spline for increasing toy data.
y_increase <- c(-0.2, 0.3, 0.5, 0.7, 0.6, 1, 0.9, 1, 1, 1)

# Creating `D` matrix and `d` vector.
d_mat <- crossprod(ispline, ispline)
d_vec <- crossprod(ispline, y_increase)

# Setting equality constraints s.t., all paramters are >= 0.
a_mat <- diag(1, ncol(ispline))
b_vec <- rep(0, ncol(ispline))

# Freeing the first parameter.
a_mat[1, 1] <- 0

# Solving the problem.
alpha_non_negative <- solve.QP(Dmat = d_mat, dvec = d_vec, Amat = t(a_mat), bvec = b_vec)$solution

# Getting fitted values (i.e., the spline).
spline_non_decreasing <- ispline %*% alpha_non_negative
```

The same goes for a monotone non-increasing spline, but this time with non-positive constraints:

```r
# Reusing the `I-Spline` stored in `ispline`.

# Fit monotone non-increasing spline for decreasing toy data.
y_decrease <- rev(y_increase)

# Creating `D` matrix and `d` vector.
d_mat <- crossprod(ispline, ispline)
d_vec <- crossprod(ispline, y_decrease)

# Setting equality constraints s.t., all paramters are <= 0.
a_mat <- diag(-1, ncol(ispline))
b_vec <- rep(0, ncol(ispline))

# Freeing the first parameter.
a_mat[1, 1] <- 0

# Solving the problem.
alpha_non_positive <- solve.QP(Dmat = d_mat, dvec = d_vec, Amat = t(a_mat), bvec = b_vec)$solution

# Getting fitted values (i.e., the spline).
spline_non_increasing <- ispline %*% alpha_non_positive
```

Which results in the following splines:

```r
plot(x, y_increase, pch = 19, cex = 1.5, col = "darkgray", main = paste0("Non-decreasing | SSQ = ", round(sum((y_increase - spline_non_decreasing)^2), 5)), cex.main = 2)
lines(x, spline_non_decreasing, lwd = 2, col = "rosybrown")
points(x, spline_non_decreasing, pch = 19, cex = 1.5, col = "steelblue")

plot(x, y_decrease, pch = 19, cex = 1.5, col = "darkgray", main = paste0("Non-increasing | SSQ = ", round(sum((y_decrease - spline_non_increasing)^2), 5)), cex.main = 2)
lines(x, spline_non_increasing, lwd = 2, col = "rosybrown")
points(x, spline_non_increasing, pch = 19, cex = 1.5, col = "steelblue")
```

[image]

I hope this makes things a bit more clear.

Answer (score 0):

From the definition of `k` in your code we know the first segment is fitting more than 2 data points.

Only if it is fitting first 2 data points and without the constraint that the function to be continuous, the spline will pass the first point. Note, if that is the case, the model is not a spline.

```
library(ggplot2)
x <- c(300, 377, 455, 533, 611, 688, 766, 844, 922, 1000)  
y <- c(0.5, 0.8, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)
group <- c(0,0,1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)
d = data.frame(x=x,y=y, group=group)
ggplot(d,aes(x,y, group=group))+geom_point()+geom_smooth(method='lm')+theme_gray(20)
```

[image]

Comment: Haitao Du, what you wrote makes sense. However, I am still confused because in [this paper](http://deleeuwpdx.net/pubfolders/splines/splines.pdf) on p. 15 (last sentence), it says that a constant function needs to be **added** to the I-Spline basis matrix. However, in the paper, the first column of the basis matrix is sometimes replaced with ones (i.e., `h <- cbind(1, h[ -1])` and other times simply another column is appended (i.e., `h <- cbind(1, h)`). Can you please shed some light on why this is the case?

Comment: I will append this to the question above.